# Wii remotes disconnect as soon as I enter a channel

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I own a original USA rvl-001 wii unmodded.
Original motion+ controllers.

They sync fine at the health and safety message. They work for long periods if I stay in the wii menu or settings page. But if I enter a Wii channel to make a wii or Wii shop channel, the remote turns off. Leds turn off.

Ver 4.3U
After cold start same results, sync well disconnect when channel starts.
Have yet to test on any games to see if it happens during gaming.

Any help is appreciated.